# Optimize PostgreSQL read-only db

Tags: postgresql

I have a large PostgreSQL database that is effectively read-only, except for very infrequent batch updates. Are there any performance optimizations I can do to make use of this? Can/should I disable visibility check for example?

The largest table:

```
CREATE TABLE "gene_measurements" (
  "gene" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "genes" ON DELETE CASCADE,
  "sample" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "samples" ON DELETE CASCADE,
  "value" REAL NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "gene_measurements_unique_1" ON "gene_measurements" ("sample", "gene") INCLUDE ("value");
```

A typical query:

```
SELECT value WHERE gene = 1 AND sample = 2
```

And the plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using gene_measurements_gene_index on gene_measurements  (cost=0.57..4.59 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=63.621..63.621 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((sample = 2) AND (gene = 1))
   Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.156 ms
 Execution Time: 63.674 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Is this having some performance issues? what exactly optimisation problem are you   trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I make multiple queries to a large table and I would like them to be faster. Everything is already indexed as far as possible. It's primarily index-only scans that I would like to be faster if possible.

Comment: Have you tried another strategies like redis? For more frequent accessed items? Are some other alternatives?

Comment: If you have a performance problem, please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are having a problem with and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you keep the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Have you read this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance

Comment: The data in the db is used e.g. for training machine learning models, and the data retrieval step is a bottleneck there. There are very many queries done, and there is no such thing as "fast enough" here; a faster implementation will simply result in me having to wait a shorter time for results. Given the simple structure of the db I think I have done all other optimizations, that's why I wanted to make use of the read-only nature of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have advanced features to make queries faster if related data is read-only.

You can get potential important performance improvements if the application know how to use this information: application code could try to cache query results for identical queries. You can also create materialized views in the database and modify application code to query materialized views instead of running the queries used to build the materialized views. But in both cases you need to modify application code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data type you index, some other index types than the default B-tree (log2(N) for search) might trade off insert/delete speed for search (read) speed – if that would help.

Also, since you use a database to feed a machine learning model with training data, consider retrieving multiple rows in a single query (~batch). Depending on the data and its indexing, this might help. Test before production.